# RxJS reduce a ReplaySubject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I'm using ReactiveX/RxJS version.

Lets say that I have a Rx.ReplaySubject that every 2 seconds it emits an object that contains an id and an array with values. I want to reduce this array of values and get the sum of them all.

The problem is that ReplaySubject is a hot observable and it never completes, at least I don't want it to complete because I want the sum of that object values every 2 seconds. But in order to use the reduce operator the observable should be completed. So, how should I proceed ?

E.G not working code:

```
var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

subject.
  map(x => x.transactions).
  // Reduce never concludes because ReplaySubject instance is not completed
  reduce((v1, v2) => v1+v2, 0).
  subscribe(function (value) {
    console.log(value)
  });

setInterval(injectData, 2000);

function injectData () {
  subject.next({id: Date.now(), transactions: [
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)}
  ]});
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using `Observable.prototype.scan()` ([RxJS documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md))

`scan()` bascially aggregates an observable and emits each successive value, unlike `reduce()` which only emits the result upon completion. (see Rx explanation of [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) and [reduce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html))

Example using OP's code (Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csdpk4ds/)):

```
var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

subject
  // note: use "selectMany" to flatten observable of observables
  .selectMany(x => Rx.Observable.fromArray(x.transactions))
  // note: use "scan" to aggregate values
  .scan((agg, val) => agg+val.value, 0)
  .subscribe(function (value) {
    console.log(value)
  });

setInterval(injectData, 2000);

function injectData () {
  subject.onNext({id: Date.now(), transactions: [
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)},
    {value: Math.round(Math.random() * 5000)}
  ]});
}
```

Another example:

The above code emits the aggregate for every transaction because of the `selectMany()`. If you only wanted it to emit once every 2 seconds, this is a great time to use `reduce()` like so (Here's another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87wjLpwv/1/)):

```
subject
  // note: use "selectMany" to flatten observable of observables
  // note: using "reduce" inside here so that we only emit the aggregate
  .selectMany(x => 
    Rx.Observable
      .fromArray(x.transactions)
      .reduce((agg, val) => agg + val.value, 0)
  )
  // note: use "scan" to aggregate values
  .scan((agg, val) => agg+val, 0)
  .subscribe(function (value) {
    console.log(value)
  });
```

Additional note:

Rx Subjects can complete; you just need to call `onCompleted()` when you're ready. If you make your subject complete you can still use `reduce()`. Compare this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5hmjsac/) with the one above.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that doing as you said, I will only get the value once. But I want to get the sum of the values every 2 seconds. That is why I can't complete the subject.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann Using `scan()` you'll get the value every 2 seconds, although because of `selectMany()` it'll also emit for every transaction every 2 seconds.

Comment: But through `.scan()` I get the sum of all the values of all the objects received. But what I want is to get the sum of each object separately.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann, ahh it sounds like you want to do my 2nd example without the .scan(). Try that out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks!